# Cannot override method with lower access than base method

Tags: .net, overriding, warnings, delphi-prism, oxygene

I am almost done with migrating my software for .NET environment. Now I am going through all the warnings and cleaning them up. Then, I ran into this problem.

Here is my class:

```
 TColorObj = class
   value:double;
   thecolor:Color;
   Constructor;
   method ReadColor(bdr:BinaryReader);
   method WriteColor(bdw:BinaryWriter);
   method Clone:TColorObj;
   method ToString:String; Override;  <<<<----this method is raising error.
 end;
```

The error is "**Cannot override method with lower access than base method**." However, if I remove the key word, **Override**, it raises a warning message, "ToString" hides a parent method." TColorObj class is not inherited from any base class as you can see.

So, do I make the class TColorObj public?

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that you should make the ToString method public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the `ToString` method public in visibility, which is what it is in `TObject`. You can't move it from  'public' to a lower visibility in a descendant.

```
TColorObj = class
   value:double;
   thecolor:Color;
   Constructor;
   method ReadColor(bdr:BinaryReader);
   method WriteColor(bdw:BinaryWriter);
public
   method Clone:TColorObj;
   method ToString:String; Override;  <<<<----this method is raising error.
end;
```

Comment: Ken White, It's Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Every class is inheriting from another class, if you don't specify a class you are inheriting from the `Object` class.

You are overrinding the `ToString` method which is public, so you have to make the overriding method public also.